# All in one Raspberry pi Server?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, pi-4, services, docker

Does Grafana server + influxDB + ChirpStack Gateway OS full runs on same Raspberry pi that RAK2245 mounted gateway? As you know latest raspberry pi 4 have 8gb ram. I will only monitor about 20-30 nodes. 
Do I need to use docker or should I install packages directly on raspian OS ?
Will sdcard wear out, if I boot OS from sdcard but install services on HDD and run from there  ?

Thanks

Comment: I know Grafana + Influx run fine even on older Pi boards but what the load would be with the LoraWan I expect depends more on the amount of data you are collecting rather than the number of nodes.  Maybe sending an email to info@rakwireless.com could get you better data than folk here due to the specialist nature of the software stack you are looking at?

Comment: I haven't heard about a RPi 4B with 8GB RAM before. I only know about 1GB, 2GB and 4GB. Please give a link, where I can purchase one with 8GB RAM.

Comment: @Ingo The Pi Hut / Pimoroni / RS / Farrell all OOS very very quickly.  Adafruit in stock but 1 per customer at https://www.adafruit.com/product/4564 News link https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/8gb-raspberry-pi-4-on-sale-now-at-75/

Comment: Hi @Andyroo, very informative links. Thanks for updating me :-)

Comment: I already have Rak2245 mounted raspberry pi 3 and current cpu load about between %5 and %10.